# How to create a enriched text viewer (notes, mark text, etc.)

Tags: android, webview

We are developing a new app, and one of the features which it should contain will be a text viewer. It needs to be a enriched text viewer with images, such as the one in the pocket app(read it later), with possibilities of scaling the font type, mark text, add notes on specific parts, so the text should able to be interactive.

Is there any existing API to start with? Could use a webview a possibility? If so, how is this interaction going to be provided, trough HTML or trough Android?

I would really appreciate any idea! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to go is to create your own EditText widget (extend EditText). EditText already provides a lot of the functionality you're asking for.

A starting point is this:

https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-Android

(Wordpress comes with a built-in rich text editor although is's fairly basic and the implementation isn't exemplary for good coding IMHO).

or this:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit

I've written a rich text editor for one of my apps and it supports character formatting (bold, italic, underline, strike through, sup- and superscript, text size, text color, background color), paragraph formatting (alignment, numbering, bullet points, indentation), links, images and undo/redo.

While EditText provides a lot of the functionality, having a real rich text editor is still a lot of work...

Using a WebView isn't a good option since it only renders a page but doesn't give you editing capabilities (which EditText does). Using HTML5 might be an option but one I haven't explored in more depth.